# Combine pipeline not receiving values

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

In the following code, which is a simplified version of a more elaborate pipeline, "Done processing" is never called for 2.

Why is that?

I suspect this is a problem due to the demand, but I cannot figure out the cause.

Note that if I remove the `combineLatest()` or the `compactMap()`, the value 2 is properly processed (but I need these `combineLatest` and `compactMap` for correctness, in my real example they are more involved).

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>([])

func process<T>(_ value: T) -> AnyPublisher<T, Never> {
    return Future<T, Never> { promise in
        print("Starting processing of \(value)")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            promise(.success(value))
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let s = PassthroughSubject<Int?, Never>()

s
    .print("Combine->Subject")
    .combineLatest(Just(true))
    .print("Compact->Combine")
    .compactMap { value, _ in value }
    .print("Sink->Compact")
    .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { process($0) }
    .sink {
        print("Done processing \($0)")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

s.send(nil)

// Give time for flatMap to finish
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
s.send(2)
```

Comment: `.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(2)) { process($0) }` will help

Comment: @Aznix that only translates the problem by 1.

Comment: I wonder if this problem isn't similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143246/why-does-publishers-map-consume-upstream-values-eagerly.

Comment: Indeed, it is rather odd (maybe even a bug). For some reason, when `combineLatest` receives an additional demand of 1 coming from `compactMap`, it doesn't forward it upstream. This happens only when the demand is received "synchronously" (as per a `print` publisher), when `compactMap` filters out a `nil` value.

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me as well. I've submitted a radar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug of `combineLatest`. When a downstream request additional demand "synchronously" (as per-`print` publisher output), that demand doesn't flow upstream.

One way to overcome this is to wrap the downstream of `combineLatest` in a `flatMap`:

```
s
    .combineLatest(Just(true))
    .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) {
        Just($0)
          .compactMap { value, _ in value }
          .flatMap { process($0) }
    }
    .sink {
        print("Done processing \($0)")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

The outer `flatMap` now creates the back pressure, and the inner `flatMap` doesn't need it anymore.